# Purescript define cons as typeclass operator

Tags: purescript

Cons operator is defined (:) is defined for Array (Array.cons) and List (Cons type constructor). So to use it in the code we should either:

```
import Data.List ((:))
```

or

```
import Data.Array ((:))
```

I wonder if it is possilbe to to define `(:)` so that it could be imported in a module and used for Array and List in the same module.

I tried to do it this way:

```
class Cons container element where
  cons :: element -> container -> container

instance consArray :: Cons (Array a) a where
  cons = Array.cons

instance constList :: Cons (List a) a where
  cons = List.Cons

infixr 6 cons as :
```

And it seems to works for basic cases:

```
arr :: Array Int
arr = 1 : [2,3]

lst :: List Int
lst = 1 : (2 :3 : Nil)
```

But some advanced cases, for example:

```
data X a = X a

getX :: ∀ msg. Int -> X msg
getX = unsafeCoerce

getCons :: ∀ msg. 
  Array (X msg) ->
  Array (X msg)
getCons children = getX 1 : children
```

But it gives the errors:

```
No type class instance was found for

    MyModule.Cons (Array (X msg2))
                       (X t3)

  The instance head contains unknown type variables. Consider adding a type annotation.

while applying a function cons
  of type Cons t0 t1 => t1 -> t0 -> t0
  to argument getX 1
while inferring the type of cons (getX 1)
in value declaration getCons

where msg2 is a rigid type variable
        bound at (line 0, column 0 - line 0, column 0)
      t0 is an unknown type
      t1 is an unknown type
```

So the question is is it generally possible to achive what I described ?

**UPD:**

This:

```
class Cons container where
  cons :: forall element. element -> container element -> container element
```

solves the issue of unified usage of the (:) when constructing Array or List.

So, after importing this `(:)` we can do in the same module:

```
arrFn :: ∀ a. a -> Array a -> Array a
arrFn el array = el : array

listFn :: ∀ a. a -> List a -> List a
listFn el list = el : el : list


-- and even this will work too:

data X a = X a

getX :: ∀ msg. Int -> X msg
getX = unsafeCoerce

getCons :: ∀ msg. 
  Array (X msg) ->
  Array (X msg)
getCons children = getX 1 : children
```

The problem is that operator defined in such way can not be used in pattern matching (as pattern maching works only with type constructors), this will give the error:

```
matchList :: List Int -> Int
matchList ls =
   case ls of
     Nil -> 0
     (x : xs) -> x
```

And it seems that is not possible to achieve fully universal usage of (:) so it would work for `Array/List` construction and `List` pattern matching.

Comment: Wow. You put a lot of effort into this question :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** you need a functional dependency.

#### Long answer

This happens because the compiler doesn't know which instance of `Cons` it should look for.

In the expression `getX 1 : children` the compiler knows that `children :: Array (X msg)`, but what is the type of `getX 1`? The function `getX` can return `X` of any type, any at all. So should it be `X Int`? Or `X String`? Or, perhaps, `X Boolean`? There is no way to tell! So the compiler just calls that type `X t3` for some, as of yet unknown, `t3`, and proceeds from there, hoping that `t3` will become known in time.

But it doesn't. The next thing the compiler has to solve is to apply the `(:)` operator. And to do that, it needs to find an instance `Cons (Array (X msg)) (X t3)`, and it doesn't know how, because it doesn't know what `t3` is, and none of the existing instances match that shape.

---

**Incidentally,** you can stop at this point and verify it. Change your instance to this:

```
instance consArray :: Cons (Array a) b where
  cons _ xs = xs
```

After that, `getCons` suddenly compiles. Why? Because the new instance head `Cons (Array a) b` does in fact match the required `Cons (Array (X msg)) (X t3)` when substituting `a ~ X msg` and `b ~ X t3`. And it never really comes up what `t3` actually is, so it can be just ignored.

**Also incidentally,** you don't even need `X` for this. You can reproduce the problem just with:

```
getX :: forall a. Int -> a
getCons :: forall msg. Array msg -> Array msg
```

`X` only serves to confuse the matter.

---

But "*is it generally possible to achieve what I described*", you ask?

Well, you haven't really *described* your desired outcome, so it's hard to tell for sure. But if I had to *guess*, it seems to me that what you really wanted is for the compiler to figure out that, since the second argument of `(:)` is an `Array (X msg)`, then the first argument must be an element of that array - namely, `X msg`, - and then use that information to infer the intended type of `getX` in this instantiation.

If that is indeed what you wanted to achieve, then what you need is a [functional dependency](https://book.purescript.org/chapter6.html#functional-dependencies):

```
class Cons container element | container -> element where
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                    |
                               this bit here
```

This piece of syntax tells the compiler that if `container` is somehow known, then `element` must be known as well.

In practice it has two effects:

1. You cannot declare any instances that have the same `container`, but different `element`s. Like, `Cons (Array Int) Int` and `Cons (Array Int) String` won't work. The compiler will complain that they violate the functional dependency.
2. But in return the compiler can now infer `element` just by knowing `container`.

So if you just add that bit, `getCons` will compile fine: the compiler will first understand that `container ~ Array (X msg)`, so it will pick the instance that matches - `Const (Array a) a`, - and from there will infer that `element ~ X msg`, and therefore `getX :: Int -> X msg`.

---

#### Old answer - written before the question got substantially changed

This has nothing to do with defining the operator in a type class. The exact same thing would happen if you just imported the operator from `Data.Array`, except the error message would be a bit better.

The issue is that you're trying to cons a value of type `X a` with an array of values of type `Tuple String (X a)`. The types are different. `Tuple String (X a)` is not the same as `X a`.

To make it work, you have to either fix the type signature so the types are the same:

```
xFn :: ∀ a. Tuple String (X a) -> Array (Tuple String (X a)) -> Array (Tuple String (X a))
xFn el list = el : list
```

Or you have to construct a tuple out of `el` before trying to cons it:

```
xFn :: ∀ a. X a -> Array (Tuple String (X a)) -> Array (Tuple String (X a))
xFn el list = Tuple "foo" el : list
```

Either way, the element will have to be converted to the tuple *at some point*. Which way is the "correct" one depends on your particular circumstances.

---

Or, alternatively, you could provide an instance `Cons (Array (Tuple String a)) a`, and convert the element to the tuple inside that instance. The absence of such instance is what the compiler is complaining about in the error message. It could look something like this:

```
instance consTuple :: Cons (Array (Tuple String a)) a where
    cons a xs = cons (Tuple "foo" a) xs
```

Except such instance wouldn't work, because it would overlap with `consArray`. So you could fix *that* by putting them in a chain:

```
instance consArray :: Cons (Array a) a where
  cons = Array.cons
else instance consTuple :: Cons (Array (Tuple String a)) a where
  cons a xs = cons (Tuple "foo" a) xs
```

Though I can't imagine what possible use case you could have for this.

Comment: Sorry actually was my mistake, I've updated OP code to show the actual error, which works with (:) from Array

Comment: Thank for elaboration, it was useful -) I've updated OP (UPD: section) to explain solution I found, though it doesn't work for List pattern matching.

Comment: I don't get your comment, sonds like an inventation not to ask question on SO)